# Comparing two arrays of objects and return final result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array of objects (array1, array2). I am trying return final array(as shown below) which eliminates duplicates from array2 but not array1. I am giving priority to array1.

```
array1 =[
    { phone: "07485454", name: "John" },
    { phone: "054554", name: "Ryan" },
]

array2 =[
    { phone: "2144564", name: "John" },
    { phone: "286456", name: "Mike" },
]
```

This is something I want as a final result. Remove duplicates from array2 only.
Final Array:

```
[
   { phone: "07485454", name: "John" },
   { phone: "054554", name: "Ryan" },
   { phone: "286456", name: "Mike" },
]
```

This is something that I have tried:

```
for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    let name = array1[i].name;
  for(let a = 0; i < array2.length; a++) {
      let newname = array2[a].name;
      if(name !== newname) {
       array1.push(
         {
           phone: array2[a].phone,
           name: array2[a].name
         });
      }
    
    console.log(array1);
  }
  
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
"errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
```

Comment: Hi, and first of all: Welcome to Stackoverflow! 

It would be really helpful and great if you worte a little bit more about the things you already tried out: What didn't work, what errors you encountered, where did you get stuck?

Right now, this questions seems like you are requesting someone else to do the implementing work for you which is not really the purpose of stack-overflow.

Comment: @DavidLosert Apologies rookie mistake

Comment: @DalalV you have a mild typo in your inner for `for(let a = 0; i < array2.length; a++) {`. It should use be `a < array2.length`. Separately you have a couple of logical errors, try updating your code and debugging what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution, you can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to contain names of your `array1` elements and pushing `array1` elements to your `result` array; subsequently add elements of `array2` which names are not contained in your `set` to your `result` array :

```js
function removeDuplicates(array1, array2) {
    const result = [];
    const set = new Set();

    for (const elem of array1) {

        result.push(elem);
        set.add(elem.name);
    } 

    for (const elem of array2) {

        if (!set.has(elem.name)) {

            result.push(elem);
        }
    }

    return result;
    
}

const array1 =[
    { phone: "07485454", name: "John" },
    { phone: "054554", name: "Ryan" }
];

const array2 =[
    { phone: "2144564", name: "John" },
    { phone: "286456", name: "Mike" }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(removeDuplicates(array1, array2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have done a typo mistake in inner for loop condition **a < array2.length**

> **Changing the array1 length will results to infinite loop**

Every time, when the **if(name !== newname)** the condition is true, inserting a new object in array1 will results to changing the array1 length.

```js
let array1 =[
    { phone: "07485454", name: "John" },
    { phone: "054554", name: "Ryan" },
]

let array2 =[
    { phone: "2144564", name: "John" },
    { phone: "286456", name: "Mike" },
]

let result = array2.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) =>{
     let index = accumulator.findIndex(item => item.name === currentItem.name);
     if(index === -1){
        accumulator.push(currentItem); 
     } 
    return accumulator;
    },array1);

console.log(result);
```